# update csv field with current time stamp value in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, csv

I am after a bash script mainly to update a CSV file containing a only row like below:

```
08/01/2017 2:58,0.32967,0.29304,nan,nan,0.989011,0.671551,12.68,83.1975,11.0937
```

So the requirement is to update the first column i.e. timestamp value with the current timestamp value (in the above format) every time when I run the script to change the value.

Comment: separate out by "," and then add timestamp to first column while keeping others as it is?

Comment: What have you tried yourself? You should parse CSV with appropriate tools (Perl, PHP, or any programming language with a built-in CSV parser, for example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a `sed` pattern which seems to work for your case:

```
sed -i "s|^[^,]*|`date '+%d/%m/%Y %H:%M'`|g" <yourfile>
```

This code will take everything from beginning which is not a coma (and will stop when it encounters one) and will replace it with the output of `date` linux command with a good formating.
the `-i` options allows you to live edit your file.